# Pair elements of two lists by condition without reusing elements

Tags: python

I have two lists that I want to join on a condition. Unlike in a relational algebra join, if more than one element of each list can be matched, only one should be selected, and shouldn't then be reused.
Also, if any of the elements of the first list don't match any of the second list, the process should fail.

Example:

```
# inputs
list1 = [{'amount': 124, 'name': 'john'},
         {'amount': 456, 'name': 'jack'},
         {'amount': 456, 'name': 'jill'},
         {'amount': 666, 'name': 'manuel'}]
list2 = [{'amount': 124, 'color': 'red'},
         {'amount': 456, 'color': 'yellow'},
         {'amount': 456, 'color': 'on fire'},
         {'amount': 666, 'color': 'purple'}]
keyfunc = lambda e: e['amount']

# expected result
[({'amount': 124, 'name': 'john'}, {'amount': 124, 'color': 'red'}),
 ({'amount': 456, 'name': 'jack'}, {'amount': 456, 'color': 'yellow'}),
 ({'amount': 456, 'name': 'jill'}, {'amount': 456, 'color': 'on fire'}),
 ({'amount': 666, 'name': 'manuel'}, {'amount': 666, 'color': 'purple'})]
```

I've written a working implementation in Python, but it seems clunky, unclear and inefficient:

```
def match(al, bl, key):
    bl = list(bl)
    for a in al:
        found = False
        for i, b in enumerate(bl):
            if key(a) == key(b):
                found = True
                yield (a, b)
                del bl[i]
                break
        if not found:
            raise Exception("Not found: %s" % a)

result = list(match(list1, list2, key=keyfunc)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to keep the dictionaries separated? I mean, could the return value be like `[{'amount': 124, 'name': 'john', 'color': 'red'}, {'amount': 456, 'name': 'jack', 'color': 'yellow'}, …]`?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I wanted to keep the `match()` function generic; the entries may not necessarily be dictionaries, or the caller may want to merge them differently (e.g. only copying a subset of the keys from one to the other).

Comment: Is `list2` allowed to have unused elements?

Comment: @EricDuminil yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could simplify your code a bit by considering the second list to be a dictionary mapping the key to list of values with the same key. This would avoid doing a linear search over the second list for each element of the first list, and also lends itself to less code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def match(al, bl, key):
    table = defaultdict(list)
    for b in bl:
        table[key(b)].append(b)
    return [(a, table[key(a)].pop(0)) for a in al]
```

The function will raise an `IndexError` exception in case the key does not reference a matching element in `bl`.

Comment: What's slightly "_meh_" with this proposal in my opinion is that the list comprehension relies on a side effect of `pop`, namely that it removes the selected element from the list.

Comment: That's nice and concise. I'd say that `pop`'s main job is to remove an element, it really isn't surprising at all IMHO. Your method doesn't detect if `b` has unused elements. I'm not sure if that's a bug or a feature. I'll ask OP.

Comment: @EricDuminil To me, a list comprehension is a declarative construct (as opposed to an imperative `for` loop) much like in Haskell (from which Python derived list comprehensions). In this mathematical sense, the value to which each element in the input sequence is mapped does not depend on other values (resp. the order in which they are processed). This independence among the elements is broken by the `pop` call (due to which you depend on a very specific order in which the list comprehension processes the elements in `al`).

Comment: @EricDuminil As for detecting unused elements in `bl`, this could be tested after the list comprehension by checking if `any(not x for x in table.values())` holds.

Comment: No need to, according to OP, your behaviour is a feature and not a bug ;) Well done!

Comment: While the `pop` in the comprehension also makes me wince, replacing it with a regular `for` loop just adds a line, and while all answers were great, I find this the clearest.

Answer (score 13):

## Theory

It might not be clear at first, but you're basically describing a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).

[image]

You're interested in finding the [maximum matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) and if it's perfect.

[NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) is a great Python library for graphs, and the [`maximum_matching`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.bipartite.html#Matching) function is already implemented. It uses the [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) and runs in \$O(n^{2.5})\$ where \$n\$ is the number of nodes.

You only have to preprocess your lists into a graph and let `networkx` do its job.

## Code

Here's a slightly modified version of a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45907094/6419007) on Stack Overflow:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def has_a_perfect_match(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False

    g = nx.Graph()

    l = [('l', d['name'],  d['amount']) for d in list1]
    r = [('r', d['color'], d['amount']) for d in list2]

    g.add_nodes_from(l, bipartite=0)
    g.add_nodes_from(r, bipartite=1)

    edges = [(a,b) for a in l for b in r if a[2] == b[2]]
    g.add_edges_from(edges)

    pos = {}
    pos.update((node, (1, index)) for index, node in enumerate(l))
    pos.update((node, (2, index)) for index, node in enumerate(r))

    m = nx.bipartite.maximum_matching(g, l)
    colors = ['blue' if m.get(a) == b else 'gray' for a,b in edges]

    nx.draw_networkx(g,
                     pos=pos,
                     arrows=False,
                     labels = {n:"%s\n%d" % (n[1], n[2]) for n in g.nodes()},
                     edge_color=colors)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

    return len(m) // 2 == len(list1)
```

As a bonus, it displays a diagram with the graph and maximum matching:

```
list1 = [{'amount': 124, 'name': 'john'},
         {'amount': 456, 'name': 'jack'},
         {'amount': 456, 'name': 'jill'},
         {'amount': 666, 'name': 'manuel'}]
list2 = [{'amount': 124, 'color': 'red'},
         {'amount': 456, 'color': 'yellow'},
         {'amount': 456, 'color': 'on fire'},
         {'amount': 666, 'color': 'purple'}]

print(has_a_perfect_match(list1, list2))
# True
```

[image]

```
list1 = [{'amount': 124, 'name': 'john'},
         {'amount': 456, 'name': 'jack'},
         {'amount': 457, 'name': 'jill'},
         {'amount': 666, 'name': 'manuel'}]
list2 = [{'amount': 124, 'color': 'red'},
         {'amount': 458, 'color': 'yellow'},
         {'amount': 456, 'color': 'on fire'},
         {'amount': 666, 'color': 'purple'}]

print(has_a_perfect_match(list1, list2))
# False
```

[image]

## Notes

The desired matching is in `m` and has a slightly different format than what you mentioned:

```
{('l', 'jack', 456): ('r', 'yellow', 456), ('l', 'jill', 456): ('r', 'on fire', 456), ('l', 'john', 124): ('r', 'red', 124), ('l', 'manuel', 666): ('r', 'purple', 666), ('r', 'red', 124): ('l', 'john', 124), ('r', 'yellow', 456): ('l', 'jack', 456), ('r', 'purple', 666): ('l', 'manuel', 666), ('r', 'on fire', 456): ('l', 'jill', 456)}
```

It does have enough information, though.

Note that the edge generation isn't optimal (it's \$O(n^{2})\$ and could be \$O(n)\$ with dicts) but it's concise and still faster than the matching algorithm. Feel free to modify it!

## Optimization

@Peilonrayz' [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/187459/139491) has a better performance because your problem is easier than the general matching problem : there are no connections between nodes with distinct ids, so a greedy algorithm works fine.

Actually, it's possible to check in 2 lines if the lists match. With a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter),  you just need to check if the distribution (e.g. `Counter({124: 1, 456: 2, 666: 1})`) is the same for both lists:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(map(key, list1)) == Counter(map(key, list2))
# True
```

Comment: Thanks! While my case is in fact simple and easier, I appreciate knowing the theory of the problem; it'll help me more when I come across similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 8):

I think you should split your code into two functions.

1. You should add some code to group your object lists together. I'd call this `group_by`.
2. Take the first from each match, and error in the `match` function.

To perform the first function, I'd use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), so that you only generate the keys that you need.
This also has the benefit of having \$O(kn)\$ performance, rather than \$O(n^k)\$.
Where \$n\$ is the amount of objects in each list, and \$k\$ are the amount of lists.

After this you can check if there are enough items to yield correctly. This is two checks, 1 that there are items in the first group. Then you check that there are the same amount of items in both groups. After this, you can use `zip` to group together items in pairs.

```
import collections


def group_by(lists, key):
    amount = range(len(lists))
    d = collections.defaultdict(lambda:tuple([[] for _ in amount]))
    for i, objects in enumerate(lists):
        for obj in objects:
            d[key(obj)][i].append(obj)
    return d


def match(al, bl, key):
    for key, groups in group_by((al, bl), key).items():
        if groups[0] and len(groups[0]) != len(groups[1]):
            raise ValueError("Missing value for {!r}".format(key))
        yield from zip(*groups)
```

The type of exception that should be raised is debatable, however it shouldn't be `Exception`.

- If you think the error is predominantly due to missing values, then using [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) would probably be best.
- If you think the error is because it requires there to be a common key, then [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#LookupError) or [`LookupError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) may be better.
- Alternately if you're planning on making an entire rational algebra Python library, create your own exceptions.

Comment: Darn it, too fast, I was thinking about something alike. I wonder, though, how missing entries are handled when considering [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) and adding a `from __future__ import generator_stop`?

Comment: I don't want to take only the first item from each group; I just don't want to reuse items in different matches. I can understand the `group_by`, but I don't see how `match` here accomplishes the expected result.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger That's a good question, there was a bug I failed to notice without that enabled. Generators stop when they encounter `StopIteration`, I thought it passed through. With the future it fails on the `iter` rather than the `raise` now. Thanks, :)

Comment: @Peilonrayz only one for each match, not in total. Please look at the expected result in the example. Feel free to suggest any improvements on the text of the question as well :)

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yes, that's what I thought. [I took advantage of this behaviour in the past](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/175126/84718)… Now I feel a bit sad, somehow, as you won't be able to rely on a generator to "swallow" a `StopIteration`.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I agree, I too have abused this in the past... In some ways it's nice as then you don't have to think of as many edge cases. But sad that our old tricks may not work, ):

Comment: @Peilonrayz thanks! Just curious, why the name `exit`?

Comment: @Peilonrayz My take is that this closely resemble the behaviour of a dict: you want a value out by providing a key. If there is no such key defined, then there is no value associated with, but you get a `KeyError`. Anyway, `KeyError`, `LookupError` or `ValueError` are both far better than `Exception`.

Comment: Nice. I didn't notice it at first, but this problem is easier than the general matching problem because every connected subgraph is complete. It means that you don't care which person you connect to which color, as long as they have the same id. You cannot go wrong, and a greedy algorithm is fine.

Comment: @EricDuminil Whilst my answer may work for the given case, I think yours is far superior in the chance that the OP wants to change their algorithm in any way.